# Confused about function addition across Lebesgue spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

For finite Lebesgue spaces, where $1 \leq p < q < r < \infty $, I want to show that for every function $f \in L^q(E)$ we have a $F \in L^p(E)$ and $G \in L^r(E)$ such that f = F + G.

I know that $ L^r(E) \subset L^q(E) \subset L^p(E)$, so if (F = f, g = 0) this is achieved trivially, but I don't know how to prove this otherwise.

I've tried going down the route of
$ L^q(E) = L^r(E) \cup L^q(E)\setminus L^r(E) $ where $ L^q(E)\setminus L^r(E) \subset L^p(E)$
I don't know how to show that if $L^q(E)$ is composed of $L^r(E)$ and a subset of $L^p(E)$ this shows we can compose such an f.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: don't put \ $ for latex command

Comment: Why not taking $F=f\boldsymbol 1_{\{|f|>C\}}$ and $G=f\boldsymbol 1_{\{|f|\leq C\}}$ ?

Comment: @Surb Thanks for your help, I'll give that a go and see where I land